# Change printing of numbers in DrRacket REPL

Tags: racket

In DrRacket with `#lang racket`, I can enter numbers in binary format like this:

```
> #b10.1
2.5
```

and I can print numbers in binary format like this:

```
> (printf (~r 2.5 #:base 2))
10.1
```

How can I make numbers print in binary automatically in the REPL, like this:

```
> #b10.1
#b10.1
```

or maybe this:

```
> #b10.1
10.1
```

?

Note that I am not just trying to print decimal numbers with "#b" appended.  When  I plot numbers, for example, `#b10.1` should behave like 2.5.

If there is no configuration setting that is designed for this purpose, then maybe it would require replacing the P in the REPL, i.e. replacing the printing part of the read-eval-print-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access and change the REPL's printer with [`current-print`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html?q=current-print#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-print%29%29). You can, for example, print out all number as binary, and print out other values with the standard `(current-print)` value. (Make sure to capture the `current-print` value before you change the parameter.

```
#lang racket

(define base-print (current-print))
(define (new-print val)
  (if (number? val)
      (display (~r val #:base 2))
      (base-print val)))
(current-print new-print)
```

Now whenever you are in the repl number values are always printed in base 2. Note though that input values are unaffected, for that check out [`current-prompt-read`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html?q=current-prompt-read#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-prompt-read%29%29)

```
> "hello"
"hello"
> #b10.1
10.1
> 2.5
10.1
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't quite work when the number is nested inside, say, a list, right?

Comment: Ya, it looks like your right. It looks like the `current-print` printer doesn't call itself recursively. :/

Comment: Seems like one would have to rewrite an entire print routine to print embedded numbers in binary via this method. :-(

Comment: It looks like there is `global-port-print-handler` as well, but it also doesn't work in the recursive case. :(

Comment: I spent some time searching through Racket source to see if I could find some code that I could easily copy and hack, or some mysterious configuration option, but gave up.  The print routines seem to be distributed across files in ways that are not easy to understand for someone unfamiliar with Racket source.  It's not the worth the trouble.  I don't need systematic binary printing that badly.  I now have workarounds based on your code, Leif.  Thanks again.